# traefik ingress wildcard support

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik, nginx-ingress, traefik-ingress

I am following traefik documentation (https://docs.traefik.io/routing/routers/), want to use PathPrefix matcher to match different paths with wildcard support, for example, to match path starting with api/v1, it should match

api/v1/customers,

api/v1alpha/customers,

api/v1beta/customers.

How to achieve it using wildcards in path syntax? Please find below my ingress yaml. I tried /api/{v1*}/customers but not working as expected.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.frontend.rule.type: PathPrefix
  labels:
    app: <app_name>
    chart: <chart_name>
    heritage: Tiller
    release: <release_name>
  name: <name>
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: <service_name>
          servicePort: 443
        path: /api/v1*/customers
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how it works, posting here if someone wants to know. We can add regular expression in path

path: /api/{version:v1([a-z]*)}/customers

Comment: Hi, can you please post whole ingress definition. Including pathType